# UILabel fit to text and positioned in a correct way

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, autolayout, custom-cell

If you first take a look at the following screenshot.

[image]

Like you can see, I have a `custom cell` with on top an `UIImageView, A UILabel, An UIimageview and another UILabel`

The first `UIImageView` should always stick to the right. That's not a problem for me.

I can't figure it out how to fix my 2 `UILabels` and the snake-like image. These should follow up each other with always the same `margin` between them. The two `UILabel` always contains names of people. So if my first `UILabel` contains a very long name, it should also looks nice.

You can compare it a little bit with what Facebook is doing.
Now my question is, how can I achieve this? I'm trying to work with `autolayout`.

Comment: Do you mean that your first label should expand its width according to text in it?

Comment: I need to find a way so that the three things line up correctly.